# The meaning of "from that of"

Tags: meaning

I came across the following sentence on a website:

> Deaf children's emotional development differs *from that of* hearing
>   children.

I am guessing that the sentence simply mean that deaf children's emotional development differs from hearing children. But I may not be aware that the phrase "*from that of*" could have changed the meaning of the sentence.

How does the phrase "*from that of*" add meaning to the sentence?

What does "*that*" refer to in the sentence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*That* is just a placeholder. Don't worry about whole phrase "from that of", just look at its individual parts:

> Deaf children's emotional development differs from **that** of hearing children.

is the same as

> Deaf children's emotional development differs from [**the emotional development**] of hearing children.

or, to put it another way:

> Deaf children's emotional development differs from hearing children[**'s emotional development**].

Comment: True, *that* is just a placeholder. And *of* is there to indicate "possessive" (as with **'s** after *deaf children*). But imho at least, they are grammatically required in OP's construction - it sounds clunky to me if *"that of"* is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

*From that of* is not a set phrase; the sentence should be parsed as

- *Deaf children's emotional development*
- *differs from*
- *that* — a pronoun referring to *[deaf children's emotional] development*
- *of hearing children*

The sentence could more explicitly be phrased as

> The emotional development of deaf children differs from the emotional development of hearing children.

Without phrasing in this manner, *differs from* becomes illogical, as it would instead express

> [...] Development differs from hearing children.

Answer (score 0):

'that of' emphasizes that the topic is emotional development rather than children.

Answer (score 0):

*From that of* is not a phrase, as others have well explained. To make it yet easier for you or whomever to comprehend that sequence of words, here are some other word sequences that include *that* in like fashion.

- This spacecraft will give scientists the opportunity to compare ***the view*** from space with ***that*** from the ground.
- Your research study fails to relate ***performance*** on one day to ***that*** on    any other day.
- Relate ***the governmental structure*** on pirate ships to ***that*** on merchant ships.
- The XAFS oscillation for all spectra shows a ***maximum amplitude*** in the
  k range from 8 to 10, and ***that*** of C1 is identical with ***that*** of C2. However, ***that*** of D1 is two times larger than ***that*** of D2.
- Between ***the title*** of the strongest and ***that*** of the first occupier, there arose perpetual conflicts.

As can be seen, the pronoun *that* in such like sentences serves to avoid repetitive specification when one or more things represent the same sort of the thing that has already been specified in that sentence or in a previous sentence. *That* is so used most often for comparisons. But, as best seen in my last two examples, any relating of one thing to an already specified thing is fair game.

Lastly, for many people, this use of *that* sounds somewhat formal. At least in everyday parlance, they would rather omit *that*, if the grammar permits it for a particular sentence. (For my last one, it probably does - *Between the title of the strongest and of the first occupier...* -, though style might not, because ambiguity is maybe introduced, but I'm not sure.) If the grammar doesn't permit it (as in your sentence, in which no one would ever say *differs from of hearing children*), they'd rather either not avoid repetition or they'd phrase the whole sentence differently. For example: *Emotional development of deaf children is different than of hearing children*. Incidentally, Americans often say *different than*. Some people criticize it as incorrect, but that's unjustified, because that collocation is used by respected writers.